# Is `mem::swap`ing a `Mutex<T>` really safe?

Tags: rust

A simple example:

```
use std::mem;
use std::sync::{Mutex};

fn main() {
    let mut orig = Mutex::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    let mut other = Mutex::new(vec![]);
    mem::swap(&mut orig, &mut other);
    println!("{:?}", other);
}
```

This program is, according to Rust, perfectly safe. Yet the implementation of `swap` (or `replace`) does not attempt to lock anything. From the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/mem.rs.html#346):

```
#[inline]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub fn swap<T>(x: &mut T, y: &mut T) {
    unsafe {
        // Give ourselves some scratch space to work with
        let mut t: T = uninitialized();

        // Perform the swap, `&mut` pointers never alias
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&*x, &mut t, 1);
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&*y, x, 1);
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&t, y, 1);

        // y and t now point to the same thing, but we need to completely
        // forget `t` because we do not want to run the destructor for `T`
        // on its value, which is still owned somewhere outside this function.
        forget(t);
    }
}
```

Using unsynchronized access on `Mutex` or `Atomic` variables seems like a recipe for trouble, so is this safe? And if it is, why?

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but having a right answer available is more useful than fairly selecting the best answer. You can give yourself a time limit or something, but eventually you should post your answer if no one else does.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: please answer this immediately, it can make building other answers on top of it easier. This is a good way of using Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I did not expect such a massive opposition, so I posted an answer of my own... I'll let the votes decide the matter then.

Comment: @Cubic: Alright, done. I'll let the votes decide then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Mutex` is `Sync`, which means it's allowed for multiple threads to access the same object concurrently. Types that make the sharing of a single object across threads possible in the first place (`Arc`, but also global variables) need to make sure that the objects they share are `Sync` to ensure integrity.

However, that doesn't avoid Rust's other aliasing rules. Specifically, only one `mut` borrow of a variable can exist at any given time, and its existence must prevent any other access to the variable. The things that make sharing possible must ensure this, as well. `Arc` does this by simply never handing out `mut` references to its pointee; you can only get non-`mut` references. This is why `Mutex::lock` takes `&self`: it must be possible to call it on a non-`mut` reference. Similarly, `Atomic*::store` and all other manipulation methods take `&self`. `static mut` variables, on the other hand, simply can only be accessed within unsafe code, where the programmer is responsible for upholding guarantees.

`mem::swap` needs `mut` references. When the compiler allows you to pass two `Mutex` objects to `swap`, it means that you never shared the mutexes with other threads to begin with - you neither put them into `Arc`, nor are they `static` (not `mut`) or `static mut` (unless you're in unsafe code).

As such, the `swap` is safe, because you're doing it within one thread.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: Mutability XOR Aliasing.

Why is `mem::swap` safe despite not locking the mutex or executing an atomic operation?

Because `&mut T` or `T` guarantees the absence of accessible aliases at compile-time.

---

The fact that a `Mutex` or `AtomicXXX` achieve safe mutation while shared across threads by either several constraining the types and operations (`AtomicXXX`) or ensuring the "Mutability XOR Aliasing" at run-time (`Mutex`) is an exception to the compile-time guarantee, but it does not supersede it.

A type can be safely mutated:

- if, at compile-time, it is not aliased (`&mut T` or `T`)
- if, at run-time, a special property of the type ensures that this is safe

types that have a special property do so **on top** of following the regular compile-time rules on which the safety of `mem::swap` and `mem::replace` hinges, and therefore in situations where the absence of aliasing can be proven at compile-time, they can be mutated without any specific synchronization.